# Mongodb database crashing after adding a "for in"

Tags: python, mongodb

My code is this:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
from termcolor import colored

cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@cryptochat.5m549.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["cryptochat"]["messaging"]
all = db.find({})

date = datetime.now().strftime("%x")

for messages in all:
    try:
        if date != messages["date"]:
            print(colored(f"Today - {messages['time']}", 'red'))
        else:
            print(colored(f"{messages['date']} - {messages['time']}", 'red'))
        print(colored("From: ", 'green'), messages['id'])
        print(colored("Message: ", 'green'), messages['message'])
        print("______________________")
    except:
        pass
    


person = input("Name: ")
message = input("Message: ")

time = datetime.now().strftime("%X")

msg = {"id" : person, "message" : message, "date" : date, "time" : time}

db.insert_one(msg)
```

Everything connects and works fine until I insert the "for messages in all". All the names and parameters match with my MongoDB ones.

Comment: The code runs correctly for me.  I have the 'for messages in all:' in the code and it runs.  can you please elaborate?

Comment: To determine why a database crashed, examine the database log.